# RealTime FireBase Query snapshotChanges firing multiple times for a batch update

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have Markers on a google map that update every 45 seconds from devices in the field. I have noticed when sending a batch updating to a list in my firebase every document updated gives me a new payload. Initially I would like to get the full payload. After that it would probably be optimal to get one load when everything is updated.

My question is, is there a method to make firebase queries asynchronous even though a listener is being attached?

The only solution I have (which I feel is very inefficient) is to put a custom asynchronous timer that only calls the function once one change is detected. This is terrible solution as multiple reads will still happen.

```
   this.eventSubscription = this.db.list('device/' + this.auth.returnClientID()).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      console.log(actions);
      for (const load of actions) {
        const x = load.payload.toJSON();
        x['device_nr'] = load.key;
        fireBaseMarkers.push(x);
      }
    })).subscribe(_ => { ...
```

So in this snippet above actions will be console logged 45 times if 45 devices are updated.

[This is the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktd5j.png)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, after going down quite a rabbit hole. I found a write up that showed firebase can't limit the amount of reads per user.
Now every time a document is updated it, it grabs the data for each one under the tree.

So instead of listening to the whole database, I am now listening to just one global timestamp and every time it changes I query the new data.

Seems like a more efficient solution, I'm open to any other solutions